# Skype online status on Windows XP on start up

Tags: skype

How can I get my Skype status to be "online" when Windows XP starts up? I see nothing in Options and a Google search turned up nothing of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype 'remembers' the last 'Online Status'. if you logout 'Online' you'll be 'Online' the next time you connect.